# Retrieving data from firestore using flutter where each document has different number of fields

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app using Flutter (i'm a flutter newbie so please excuse me if this is a stupid question) and basically one functionality of my app is a todo list. The thing is that this app has both an elderly and caretaker interface so the idea is that each task is assigned by the caretaker and stored to firebase and the elderly then just sees the task. So the way I am doing it is that each caretaker's userid is the docid of the document in which all the tasks for the elderly are stored. The problem is each document will have variable number of fields and the field name does not really matter. For example I might only give my mom 2 tasks but someone else might give their father 6 tasks for that day. I am using streambuilder but I need a way where once the document is found(using Uid) i can retrieve all the fields and make each field a checkbox. I can't hardcode and put

```
return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                          child: Text(document['task1'])),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
```

because even though the field name might be known, the number of fields is unknown. Above lines work for a todo list with 1 task but nothing more.
P.S I can figure out checkbox part, I am just returning a Text widget for simplicity.
Thank You in advance.
[image: authentication db]
[image: 4 tasks of one user]
[image: 2 tasks of another user]

Comment: Hello, is safe to assume all your documents are named `task1`, `task2`, `task3` etc?

Comment: Also, please post your database structure.

Comment: done! please see the authentication db and two example user documents.

Comment: Could you checkout the answer I posted to see if that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `document` is a `Map` object, you can use the [entries](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Map/entries.html) property of the `Map` class. It fetches each key-value pair in the `Map`.

You can update your code to:

```
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        children: document.data().entries
                         .map((mapEntry) => Container(
                           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                           child: Text(mapEntry.value)))
                         .toList(),
                    ));
                  }).toList(),
                );
```

This loops through the key-value pairs in the `document`, maps each value into a Text widget and then puts them together in a `List`.
This list is then passed to a `Column`.

Comment: i am getting an error that the 'entries' isn't defined for the type QueryDocumentSnapshot and toList() isnt defined for the type 'Container' , i pasted ur code as is but is it a delimeter error..please see image below.

Comment: Taking a look now.

Comment: I've edited the code now. This should fix the errors.

Comment: the entries keyword is showing as an error, can you see what the problem is. i apologize, i am new to flutter so i can't figure out that many errors yet ..ive updated my answer to show a pic of the error.

Comment: Hi, I've changed document.data.entries to document.data().entries. That should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

the entries keyword is shown as an error
[image: error]

and i moved the .map((mapEntry)..to the top with entries, doesnt fix it, it just self formats back to this.